# MYSQL nested query newbie question

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1093

I am trying to increment 'sellingDate' field that's in 'company' table.

```
UPDATE company 
   SET sellingDate = ((SELECT DATE_ADD((SELECT sellingDate 
                                          FROM company 
                                         WHERE cid = '35'), INTERVAL 1 DAY))) 
 WHERE cid = '35';
```

This query gives me an error saying:

> Error Code: 1093
>   You can't specify target table 'company' for update in FROM clause

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Thank you everyone for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE company 
   SET sellingDate = DATE_ADD(sellingDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
 WHERE cid = '35'
```

MySQL doesn't allow a subquery in an UPDATE statement against the same table, but the subquery is unnecessary for this example.  For some odd reason a self-join in an UPDATE statement won't return the 1093 error though it's the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UPDATE company SET sellingDate = DATE_ADD(sellingDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) WHERE cid = '35';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use sub query from same table which you are updating 
However you can achieve same by this query

```
UPDATE company SET sellingDate=DATE_ADD(sellingDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) WHERE cid = '35';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use a nested query to increment this field?

```
UPDATE company SET sellingDate = DATE_ADD(sellingDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) WHERE cid = '35';
```